# Setting countdown timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set a countdown timer. The time remaining in the format of `"00:00:00"`.

I need to create a countdown timer displaying minutes and seconds within four `<span></span>` elements.

For example, when I have 56 minutes and 45 secs, its value should be set as follows:

```
5-with in one span element
6-with in second span element
4-with in third span element
5-with in last span element
```

or

```
<span>5</span><span>6</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
```

Comment: Did you Google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460474/how-to-set-a-timer-in-javascript?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221801/javascript-jquery-time-count-down?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610580/create-a-count-up-timer-in-javascript-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started and push you in the right direction.  The rest is up to you.

```
var start = 5;

function countdown() {
    $("#spanId").html(start--);
    if (start)
       setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}
countdown();
```